# how to pass user data to a modal?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

how can i send user data when opening the modal?

```
<button type="button"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#inputFormModal{{ $usuario->id }}" wire:click="OpenModal({{$usuario->id}})"> Open User</button>
@livewire('show-modal')
```

I make the Emit function to send the user's id:

```
public function OpenModal($id)
{
    $this->emit('OpenModal', $id);
}
```

**ShowModal Component:**

```
protected $listeners = ['OpenModal'];
public $idmodal;

public function OpenModal($id)
{
   $this->idmodal = $id;
}

public function render()
{
    $user = User::find($this->idmodal);

    return view('livewire.show-modal', [
        'user' => $user,
    ])->layout('livewire.base');
}
```

**Modal Error:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$user->name}}" aria-label="email" wire:model="name">
```

**Attempt to read property "name" on null**

Why can't it find the user data?, help please

Comment: you user can have null name? you can put on view: `{$user->name ?? ''}}` to pass the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mount function that captures liveware events with passed data, in your case:

```
@livewire('show-modal',['user'=>$user])




public function mount($user)
  {

  }
```